# Regex cuts off number

Tags: regex

I want to extract only the order number from this text:

> magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)Marketplace Bestellnummer:
>   306-3584295-9664328** BUSINESS ORDER **Purchase Order Number: ?()_!

To filter I get this regex: `[^.//][a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜ_\(\):!\?\.\*\n\n\r\n$ ]+`

Strangely, the command cuts off the last number from the order number.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why not something like `\d{3,}-\d{7,}-\d{7,}` or `\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1HnmG/1).

Comment: what is your desired outcome? this regex is not even remotely doing what you want.

Comment: I need to extract this ordernumber and copy it into an other column of a sql table. The only whay how it works is to use regexp_replace and update everything into the neww column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it cuts of the last digit is because your match starts with `[^.//]` which will also match a single digit. Then this part `[a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜ_\(\):!\?\.\*\n\n\r\n$ ]+` will match an asterix but will not match a digit. So your match starts including the 8

`8** BUSINESS ORDER **Purchase Order Number: ?()_!`

Keeping your original regex, one way you might solve this is by also not matching a digit in the first part `[^\d./]`

Your regex could be a bit more compact like `[^\d./][a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜ_():!?.*$\s]+`

Note that you use a character class and that you just could add the '\n' once. You also dont have to escape the dot, asterix and the question mark.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f7Rmf7/1)

If matching is an option, you might consider using `\b\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}\b`
or a somewhat broader match like `\d+(?:-\d+){2}`

Comment: Perfect! This way it works :-). 
But I still have a little problem. At the end, line breaks are made. By using \n\n\r\n$ it sometimes cut off the las number. 
Why is that? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Those character are inside a character class and do not mean at the end of the string. $ here means literally a dollar sign. Your character class could be `[^./][a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜ_():!?.*\r\n$ ]+`

Comment: Thanks for your update. But \r\n$ is cutting sometimes the last digit of the number. Here one example text:
magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)Marketplace Bestellnummer: 304-2453412-8821115

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce that. Can you take a look at this example? https://regex101.com/r/7HX5Wg/1 By the way,  why don't you match instead of replace?

Comment: Unfrotunatelly not.Not for my purposes. I have to search for an other way to solve this problem. Thakns anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
Bestellnummer:\s([\d-]+)
```

then grap `Group 1`, that will contain the `order number`.

The regex Works by matching '`Bestellnummer:` ' before it creates a match Group containing any number of digits and hyphens. This Group is what you want.